# Cannot save data in database in grails

Tags: database, grails

I have created a simple form and trying to save data into database. whenever i input data and press Save button it says Error, but when I manually type the url it shows success but the data isn't saved in the database.

**Domain:**

```
package com.anurag

class List {
    String name
    Date joining
    int phone
    boolean permanent
    float salary

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package com.anurag

import groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult

class ListController {
    static defaultAction = "showData"
    ListService listService

    def showData = {
        java.util.List<GroovyRowResult> result = listService.getList()
        [result: result]
    }

    def inputData = {

    }

    def saveData = {
        def list = new List(params)
        if(list.validate()) {
            list.save()
            render "Success!"
        }
        else{
            list.errors.allErrors.each{
                println it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**inputData.gsp:**

```
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<g:form controller="list" action="saveData">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <g:textField name="name"/><br/>

    <label>Joining: </label> <g:textField name="joining"/><br/>

    <label>Phone No.: </label> <g:textField name="phone"/><br/>
    <label>Permanent: </label> <g:textField name="permanent"/><br/>
    <label>Salary: </label> <g:textField name="salary"/><br/>

    <g:actionSubmit value="Save"/>
</g:form>
```

Comment: what error?  and what makes you sure you are not using `java.util.List` there?

Comment: it says error 404: list/showData.jsp not found

Comment: please see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews `Selecting Views`.  you have to either tell what to render or provide the "view"

Answer (score 0):

You are using here `<g:actionSubmit value="Save"/>` in this case `action` of the form will be determined by `value` attribute of actionSubmit button (as you have not used 'action' attribute in g:actionSubmit tag) i.e here your form will be submitted at `save` action and not the action defined in form tag.You can simply use `<g:submitButton name="save" value="Save" />` tag If you want form should submit at url defined in form tag.

For further reference you can check [Grails doc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html)